# Explain kant's conception of causality as an a priori category prescribed by the understanding to all possible objects of experience?

Tags: epistemology, kant, causation, causality

How does causality relate to the a priori and experience? I am having trouble connecting the dots. Any help would be great!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. Is this an essay assignment? Non-specific questions like this are better addressed by reading encyclopedias, e.g. [SEP's Kant and Hume on Causality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-hume-causality/). We take more pointed questions that come up after the general reading on a topic.

Comment: This question takes a book for a good answer, thus is not a good fit for this site. One of the books that give a good answer is Henry E. Allison's
*Kant's Transcendental Deduction: An Analytical-Historical Commentary*. If this is indeed an essay assignment, I take it to be a bad one at that since any careful and critical answer has to be well beyond what can be given within the word count of an essay.